# Enable completions-popup in Sublime Text 3

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Unlike most other packages, PHP suppresses the completions/snippets-popup, forcing you to type the whole trigger before hitting tab and making it impossible to choose between different snippets with the same trigger.

I'm looking for a way to enable the completions-popup in PHP (or for all languages, overriding their default).

**What I've tried:**

The PHP Package includes the file "Completion Rules.tmPreferences" with

```
<key>cancelCompletion</key>
<string>^\s*(\}?\s*(else|do|try)|(class|function)\s*[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$</string>
```

Afaik, this is what suppresses the popup. I changed the regex to an unmatchable selector

```
<key>cancelCompletion</key>
<string>/(?!)/</string>
```

and saved it with PackageResourceViewer so that it should override the default settings file, however, even after restarting in case the file is only loaded once, the popup still doesn't appear.

**Edit:**

As Enteleform pointed out, the popup works inside `<?php ?>`, the problem occurs when in a PHP file, but outside the php. The scope is (embedding.php, text.html.basic).

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue, and have the same value for the `cancelCompletion` key. Steps: [1] Open new file & set `PHP` syntax [2] Insert basic PHP template: `<!DOCTYPEhtml><html><body><?php __PHP_CONTENT__ ?></body></html>` [3] Test auto-completions in the `__PHP_CONTENT__ ` region. Auto-completions work as expected.

Comment: I'm in the middle of laravel right now, so I didn't even think to test with <?php ?>. It works inside those, so thanks for your input. However, I'm still trying to get it to work outside of those, esp. blade-Templates; scope (embedding.php, text.html.basic). 

Both PHP and Laravel Snippets work if typed exactly, so the scope applies and the Laravel Snippets Package doesn't even have a .tmPreferences to override the PHP one. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried changing the scope @ `Completion Rules.tmPreferences` & `PHP.sublime-completions`, but haven't had much luck. It's weird - if I change it to `source.python`, it will stop functioning @ PHP files and will work properly @ Python files. However, I tried a bunch of combinations of `source.php`, `embedding.php`, & `text.html.basic`; and none of them seem to work for your intended usage case. @KeithHall might know of a solution, he's a lot better with scope-related matters.

Comment: @Enteleform unfortunately, you can't ping other SO members unless they're already associated with a post - wrote it, edited it, commented on it. I would definitely open an issue (either one of you) [here](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues) with `[PHP]` in the subject line explaining everything that's going on. `embedding.php` must be a new scope, but I don't know if it's a base scope or what. Either Keith or wbond should be able to shed some light on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto completion is not automatically shown as you type HTML by default, as you have experienced. This is controlled by the `auto_complete_selector` preference, which defaults to the following selector: `"meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc"`. As you can see, it is enabled for the `source` scope (except when inside comments and strings), which is why it works in PHP, and for the `meta.tag` scope.

Now, the HTML syntax definition only assigns the `meta.tag` scope when there is at least one character following the `<`. i.e. typing `<d` will show the auto completion list automatically.

To change it to always show HTML completions, you can change your preference to `"text.html, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc"`
- i.e. change the `meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin` to `text.html`.

Alternatively, to always show completions as you type for any language, you can change your preference to the empty string `""`. However, I would recommend keeping the functionality of not showing auto completions inside strings and comments, and using `"- comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc"` instead. It is also worth noting that typing word separator characters does not trigger autocompletion automatically - you have to type the first letter of something that can be autocompleted.

This preference should be added to your `Preferences` -> `Settings - User` file.

Note: as you are overriding a default preference, it is possible that the default value could change in future ST3 builds. It may therefore be worth checking the default (from `Preferences` -> `Settings - Default`) occasionally, in case having a different value will negatively affect your experience.

Comment: Thank you so much. I went with `"meta.tag - punctuation.definition.tag.begin, source - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc, embedding.php - comment - string.quoted.double.block - string.quoted.single.block - string.unquoted.heredoc"` which mimics the old exceptions and seems specific enough to not clash with future updates.